# Dynamic variable in flutter. Any better way to do this?

Tags: flutter, dart

**[Edited]** I have this application with multilevel user application where I have functions based on roles. Currently, I am saving user response in shared preferences and fetching it by getting it's instance whenever I need it. And also, I am using different screens and different widgets for each role. But there has to be a better way to do it. I am so confused with singleton pattern and making global variables in dart.

Here's my code:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
    var user=prefs.getString("role");
    runApp(MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<RoleNotifier>(
          create: (_) => RoleNotifier(user),
        ),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ));
  });
}
```

```
void setRole(String role) async {
    Provider.of<RoleNotifier>(context, listen:false).setUser(role);
    await SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs){
      prefs.setString("role", role);
   });
  }
_login() async {
    try {
      setState(() {
        _isbusy = true;
      });
      var data = {"username": _emailc.text, "password": _pass.text};
      var response = await CallApi().postData(data, 'login');
      SharedPreferences local = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      var res = response.data;
      print(res);
      if (res['success']) {
        local.setString('token', res['data']['token']);
        if (res['data']['role'] == 'admin') {
              setRole(res['data']['role']);
              local.setString('info', json.encode(res['data']));
              Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AdminDashBoard()));
        } else if (res['data']['role'] == 'dev') {

               setRole(res['data']['role']);
              local.setString('post', res['data']['role']);
              local.setString('info', json.encode(res['data']));
              Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DevDashBoard()));
        } else if (res['data']['role'] == 'user') {
              setRole(res['data']['role']);
              local.setString('post', res['data']['role']);
              local.setString('info', json.encode(res['data']));
              Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserDashBoard()));
        } 
      } else {
        print('error');
        setState(() {
          _isbusy = false;
        });
        showSimpleFlushbar(context, "An Error Occurred!");
      }
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e);
      setState(() {
        _isbusy = false;
      });
      print(e.response.data);
      print(e.response.headers);
      print(e.response.request);
      showSimpleFlushbar(context,
          "Login Failed! Please Check your credentials and try again.");
    }
  }
```

And to access the variables:

```
SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
      var data = jsonDecode(prefs.getString("info"));
      setState(() {
        email = data['email'];
        post = data['role'];
      });
    });
```

The problem is, I have to run this on initState in every screen and there is a delay in fetching data which throws an exception for small time. 
I just figured out this is working.

```
(Provider.of<RoleNotifier>(context).getUser()=="admin")?AdminWidget():SizedBox(),
```

Now I can access the data from anywhere using provider. But is there any better way to do this? I've heard a lot about singleton pattern and in my case even though it works, it seems like I am doing something wrong. Like I am listening to the value that is static immediately after login is completed.

Comment: I just figured this out and I am doing provider+shared prefs like you mentioned. Is there any better way to do this? I have edited  my post on what I've changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SharedPreferences prefs;// file level global variable

main(){
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((p)=>prefs = p);
    // do whatever
    runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Now, don't use `SharedPreferences.getInstance()` when needed but use the global variable
created.

Like

`prefs.getString('name');`

or

`prefs.setString('foo','bar');`

For example

```
class Foo extends StatelessWidget{
    Widget build(context){
        var name = prefs.getString('name');// don't use var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        return Text("name is $name");
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising. By doing this, I can use prefs where ever I want and and instance is created the moment app is launched. I don't have to await instance anywhere to access the shared preferences. Before I accept this as answer, I would like to make sure of these two things. 
1. Is this the singleton pattern?
2. Is this solution better than what I have done with shared prefs + provider?
I would appreciate if you could answer these for me.

Comment: 1. yes it is singleton 2. It depends on your code structure. But it is better than using 'await' each time.

Comment: Also, I have some features where shared preferences values gets updated within the  app and updated values are used. In that case, I guess, values don't get updated because the instance is already created at the start. Is that the case?

Comment: No, that is because you may be using shared prefs incorrectly. The correct way to use such things is by the provider where values, when updated, reflect the changes throughout the app. SharedPreferences are used to set values that are needed for app launch configs. So, let say you have themes(dark and light) in your app. Use the provider to change the theme and its result is seen instantly throughout the app. Whenever the theme is changed or the app is closed the current theme should be saved to SharedPrefs, the next time app is used the values are initially read from prefs, as start values.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a User class and extend it with Provider?

Then based on the Consumers to build dynamic widgets you can pump out what ever you want based on the User.role for the selected user.

In your Singleton you can add a Singleton().selectedUser var and once a user logs in or what ever process they follow you can assign it to that. Use this selectedUser var for your Provider.value.

If you need example code let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. And I did implement provider to set the value. But the problem is, It works when I log in for the first time because there, I set the value in change notifier. But next time I bypass login by using key from shared preferences and it doesn't work because the value hasn't been set in that instance. I might be doing it incorrectly.  It would be great to have a look at an example code.